# Google Cloud Datastore emulator import does not work

Tags: import, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage, emulation

I have configured datastore emulator on Windows PC and it is running successfully.
However, command to import data does not work.

I checked a [official document](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import) .

I tried two commands below (difference is input_url or inputUrl):

```
curl -X POST localhost:8085/v1/projects/<project-id> -H “Content-Type:application/json” -d {"input_url":"C:\datastore\<path-to-overall_export_metadata>.overall_export_metadata"}


curl -X POST localhost:8085/v1/projects/<project-id> -H “Content-Type:application/json” -d {"inputUrl":"C:\datastore\<path-to-overall_export_metadata>.overall_export_metadata"}
```

I got response below:

> {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Payload isn't valid 
>   for request.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

Comment: 400 means that the argument is not what the requested was expecting, maybe the missing content type header is the issue. Try adding to curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

Comment: @Pievis Thank you for your comment. As your comment, I did’t add -H option by mistake. However, I still get same error ‘404 Payload isn't valid for request’. I got ‘Not found’ error in case I use single quotation, so I use double quotation. I edited my post about curl command. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The value passed to -d needs to be a valid JSON string. I think in this case it's just a matter of escaping the backslashes, e.g.:

```
{"inputUrl":"C:\\datastore\\<path-to-overall_export_metadata>.overall_export_metadata"}
```